# Вывод в конце запрос MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день. Написал запрос

```
SELECT dat, ticket,eventtype FROM [DAMASK].[DBO].[Monitor]  
WHERE dat >= CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) AND eventtype = 1 AND ticket<>'' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Он выводит такую таблицу. 
Как сделать подсчет кол-ва строк по столбцу data  или вывести значение rows в конечном итоге в одну ячейку? Т.е я нашел мне нужные данные и теперь хочу, чтобы кол-во записей по столбцу data вывелось в одну ячейку как итог.
Заранее спасибо

```
|id|data|   
|1 |2015|  
|2 |2016|  
|3 |2015|   
|4 |2015|    
|5 |2016|  
|6 |2015|  
|7 |2016|  
|8 |2015|  
|9 |2016|
```

Comment: Количество записей в любом столбце одинаково. может вы имели ввиду количество уникальных значений ? Если просто количество не NULL значений - то `select count(data) from ...`, а если уникальных то `select count(distinct data) from ...`. И ваш запрос ну ни как не может выдавать ту таблицу что вы привели в вопросе. В запросе у вас 3 колонки, а тут две. И тут какое то поле id, которого нет в запросе. А лучше всего приведите входные данные и образец выходных что бы было сразу понятно что из чего должно получится

Comment: Выдает конечно три столбца. Просто выборка идет по трем признакам, разные признаки у значений. В конечном итоге я хотел бы увидеть одну ячейку с общим кол-во записей по столбцу № 2. Например |107|

Comment: Я уже написал как получить количество. что то в этом не получается ?

Comment: И уточните чем в вашем понимании отличается количество по столбцу два от количества по столбцу 1 ?